# mapping function returns null, orElseGet is being called when i don't want it to be

Tags: java

Let's say I have the following function:

```
private void func(final String name, final String zipcode) {
    this.userService.findUser(userId).map(user -> {
        this.userService.update(user.getId(), zipcode);
        return null; // because a return is needed
    }).orElseGet(() ->  this.userService.create(name, zipcode));
}
```

I can't change **update** and **findUser** signatures (void and Optional being the relevant parts):

```
public void update(final UUID userId, String zipcode)

public Optional<User> findUser(final UUID userId)
```

I have to return something in the function being given to the map, but returning null will make orElseGet get called everytime.

Is the only way to use map correctly in this case (not calling orElseGet when a user is found) to return something else other than null?

If so, is there another good way to write this code?

Returning something random just to make it work doesn't feel correct.

Comment: You can return the updated `User` from your userService update operation and return it instead of returning a null.

Comment: Thanks, but i can't change update. Edited for clarity

Comment: If you want to leave the value unchanged you should return `user` instead of null inside your map method call.  However, I would argue that this use of the map method is not very intuitive.  What you are effectively doing is running a line of code only if the Optional holds a value.  The standard way to do this would be to use an if statement on the [`isPresent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent()) method of the Optional.  If this doesn't work for your use case for whatever reason, I would leave a comment for clarity.

Comment: And there is no need to change the update() method header to follow Vini's advice.  You're changing the return value of the lambda function in your map() method call, not the return value of the update() method.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong when you say this use is not very intuitive, is it because it's only a single line? Would it be intuitive if it was a block of code?

Comment: I understand i can return the user from findUser, but not the updated user as it is not being returned to me. Unless i do a setZipcode and return it, if that's what you are suggesting.

Comment: You should not use `map` except when you actually need to produce a result.  If you don't need to produce a result, you shouldn't use `map`.  That's the issue, not the single-line-ness.

Comment: Seeing the accepted answer made it all clear. Thanks everyone for the comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Optional.ifPresentOrElse(). For example:

```
private void func(final String name, final String zipcode) {
this.userService.findUser(userId)    
    .ifPresentOrElse(user -> this.userService.update(user.getId(), zipcode),
    () -> this.userService.create(name, zipcode));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling with the syntax for that